# The best way to resize canvas with its objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, responsive-design, fabricjs

I have a Fabric.js canvas inside in a responsive design with boostrap.
To resize the canvas, i use **canvas.setDimensions({width:w, height:h});**
From the width and the height of the current window clientWidth and clientHeight. Here is my canvas and his container :

```
<div style="width: 100%;" class="canvas-container">
   <canvas id="canvas" class='img-fluid'></canvas>
</div>
```

When the canvas is resized, for each object in the canvas i change proportionally their size and location. I calculate a factor to apply to each object's top/left/width/height using the original and new canvas sizes. This code runs every time the canvas is resized:

```
 function resizeCanvas() {
    const outerCanvasContainer = $('.canvas-container')[0];
    const ratio = canvas.getWidth() / canvas.getHeight();
    const containerWidth   = outerCanvasContainer.clientWidth;
    const containerHeight  = outerCanvasContainer.clientHeight;
    const scale = containerWidth / canvas.getWidth();
    const zoom  = canvas.getZoom() * scale;

    canvas.setDimensions({width: containerWidth, height: containerWidth / ratio});
    canvas.setViewportTransform([zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0]);

    canvas.calcOffset();
    canvas.forEachObject(function(o) {
       o.setCoords();
    });

        if (canvas.width != containerWidth) {
          var scaleMultiplier = newWidth / canvas.width;
          var objects = canvas.getObjects();
          var factorX = newWidth / canvas.getWidth();
          var factorY = newWidth / canvas.getHeight();
          for (var i in objects) {
              objects[i].scaleX = objects[i].scaleX *factorX;
              objects[i].scaleY = objects[i].scaleY *factorX;
              objects[i].left = factorX * objects[i].left;
              objects[i].top = factorX * objects[i].top ;
              objects[i].setCoords();
          };

          canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * factorX);
          canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * factorY);
          canvas.renderAll();
          canvas.calcOffset();
        }
}

$(window).resize(resizeCanvas);
```

Resizing works fine, all the objects change their dimensions correctly.
The problem is that most objects cannot be selected after the canvas is resized.
Also, clicking on empty areas of the canvas sometimes selects objects...

```js
// Create a new instance of Canvas
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
canvas.setDimensions({width: 1000, height: 1000});
resizeCanvas();

// Create a new Text instance
var text = new fabric.Text('Texte', {
    fill: '#000',
    fontSize: 100,
    borderColor: '#000',
    cornerColor: '#000'
});

// Render the Text on Canvas
canvas.add(text);
canvas.centerObject(text);        
canvas.setActiveObject(text);

// function to resize canvas and its objects
function resizeCanvas() {
    const outerCanvasContainer = $('.canvas-container')[0];
    const ratio = canvas.getWidth() / canvas.getHeight();
    const containerWidth   = outerCanvasContainer.clientWidth;
    const containerHeight  = outerCanvasContainer.clientHeight;
    const scale = containerWidth / canvas.getWidth();
    const zoom  = canvas.getZoom() * scale;

    canvas.setDimensions({width: containerWidth, height: containerWidth / ratio});
    canvas.setViewportTransform([zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0]);

    canvas.calcOffset();
    canvas.forEachObject(function(o) {
      o.setCoords();
    });

  if (canvas.width != containerWidth) {
    var containerWidth_ = $(outerCanvasContainer).width();
    var scaleMultiplier = containerWidth_ / canvas.width;
    var objects = canvas.getObjects();
    var factorX = containerWidth_ / canvas.getWidth();
    var factorY = containerWidth_ / canvas.getHeight();
    for (var i in objects) {
        objects[i].scaleX = objects[i].scaleX *factorX;
        objects[i].scaleY = objects[i].scaleY *factorX;
        objects[i].left = factorX * objects[i].left + 15;
        objects[i].top = factorX * objects[i].top + 10;
        objects[i].setCoords();
    };
    
    canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * factorX);
    canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * factorY);
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.calcOffset();
  }
}

$(window).resize(resizeCanvas);
```

```css
body { background-color:#000 }
#canvas{border: 1px solid #666}
.upper-canvas {max-width: 1000px;max-height: 1000px;}
.container{margin:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/521/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/master/lib/aligning_guidelines.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container mx-auto">
   <div class="col-12">           
      <div class="row">
        <div style="width: 100%;" class="canvas-container">
            <canvas id="canvas" class='img-fluid'>
              <p>This is fallback content for users of assistive technologies or of browsers that don't have full support for the Canvas API.</p>
            </canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

As you can see in the snippet, when page is loaded, you can modify the text like you want but if you click to "Full page", you cannot do it anymore or it become difficult to do it.

Here a video explaining the problem : https://a.uguu.se/pgOYGfJy.webm

I have done a lot of research on the internet and tried a lot of things and i would like to know **if anyone knows the best way to make a responsive design while keeping the correct values of the canvas objects** in order to avoid this problem happening.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Fabric.js adds the `.canvas-container` wrapper automatically. You don't
   have to provide it. Your code ends up creating two
   `.canvas-container` elements. That disturbs the layout.
2. You can directly use `window.innerHeight`, instead of setting width 100% on parent container and reading it from it.

Assuming you want the canvas to fit the viewport you can try this:

```js
// Create a new instance of Canvas
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

let width = window.innerWidth <= 1000 ? window.innerWidth : 1000;
let height = window.innerHeight <= 1000 ? window.innerHeight : 1000;
canvas.setDimensions({width, height});

// do initial resizing after we add the text
setTimeout(resizeCanvas);

// Create a new Text instance
var text = new fabric.Text('Texte', {
  fill: '#000',
  fontSize: 60,
  borderColor: '#000',
  cornerColor: '#000',
});

// Render the Text on Canvas
canvas.add(text);
canvas.centerObject(text);
canvas.setActiveObject(text);

// function to resize canvas and its objects
function resizeCanvas() {
  const newWidth = window.innerWidth <= 1000 ? window.innerWidth : 1000;
  const newHeight = window.innerHeight <= 1000 ? window.innerHeight : 1000;

  if (canvas.width != newWidth || canvas.height != newHeight) {
    const scaleX = newWidth / canvas.width;
    const scaleY = newHeight / canvas.height;
    var objects = canvas.getObjects();
    for (var i in objects) {
      objects[i].scaleX = objects[i].scaleX * scaleX;
      objects[i].scaleY = objects[i].scaleY * scaleY;
      objects[i].left = objects[i].left * scaleX;
      objects[i].top = objects[i].top * scaleY;
      objects[i].setCoords();
    }
    var obj = canvas.backgroundImage;
    if (obj) {
      obj.scaleX = obj.scaleX * scaleX;
      obj.scaleY = obj.scaleY * scaleY;
    }

    canvas.discardActiveObject();
    canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * scaleX);
    canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * scaleY);
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.calcOffset();
  }
}

$(window).resize(resizeCanvas);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/521/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/master/lib/aligning_guidelines.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="container mx-auto">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <canvas id="canvas" class="img-fluid">
      <p
       >This is fallback content for users of assistive technologies or of browsers that
       don't have full support for the Canvas API.</p
      >
     </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want square canvas then don't use `window.innerHeight` or replace `window.innerHeight` with `window.innerWidth` in above code.
If you want canvas to fit entire window, without removing parent elements, then add following CSS rule:

```css
.canvas-container {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

---

**Square canvas**  Objects will scale in proportion.

```js
// Create a new instance of Canvas
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

let width = 1000;
let height = 1000;

canvas.setDimensions({width, height});

// do initial resizing after we add the text
setTimeout(resizeCanvas);

// Create a new Text instance
var text = new fabric.Text('Texte', {
  fill: '#000',
  fontSize: 60,
  borderColor: '#000',
  cornerColor: '#000',
});

// Render the Text on Canvas
canvas.add(text);
canvas.centerObject(text);
canvas.setActiveObject(text);

// function to resize canvas and its objects
function resizeCanvas() {
  const newWidth = window.innerWidth <= 1000 ? window.innerWidth : 1000;

  if (canvas.width != newWidth) {
    const scaleX = newWidth / canvas.width;
    var objects = canvas.getObjects();
    for (var i in objects) {
      objects[i].scaleX = objects[i].scaleX * scaleX;
      objects[i].scaleY = objects[i].scaleY * scaleX;
      objects[i].left = objects[i].left * scaleX;
      objects[i].top = objects[i].top * scaleX;
      objects[i].setCoords();
    }
    var obj = canvas.backgroundImage;
    if (obj) {
      obj.scaleX = obj.scaleX * scaleX;
      obj.scaleY = obj.scaleY * scaleX;
    }

    canvas.discardActiveObject();
    canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * scaleX);
    canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * scaleX);
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.calcOffset();
  }
}

$(window).resize(resizeCanvas);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/521/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/master/lib/aligning_guidelines.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="container mx-auto">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <canvas id="canvas" class="img-fluid">
      <p
       >This is fallback content for users of assistive technologies or of browsers that
       don't have full support for the Canvas API.</p
      >
     </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Bigger canvas:** size is not an issue. See in full page.

```js
// Create a new instance of Canvas
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

let width = 2000;
let height = 2000;
canvas.setDimensions({width, height});

// Create a new Text instance
var text = new fabric.Text('Texte', {
  fill: '#000',
  fontSize: 100,
  borderColor: '#000',
  cornerColor: '#000',
});

// Render the Text on Canvas
canvas.add(text);
canvas.setActiveObject(text);
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/521/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/master/lib/aligning_guidelines.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <canvas id="canvas" class="img-fluid">
      <p
       >This is fallback content for users of assistive technologies or of browsers that
       don't have full support for the Canvas API.</p
      >
     </canvas>
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. Your code is good but the object dont get the correct size when window resizing. I solved the problem by myself by checking the width during the window resizing and set the maximum to 1000px. Canvas cant get more than 1000px size. Thank you anyway for taking the time to try to help me.

Comment: @SKJ yeah, the main issue was after resizing, it was hard to get hold of the text. Limiting size to 1000px was trivial. I've updated the code. If your problem is solved then you could accept this as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to give you this news, but probably your effort is superfluous. :(

It seems that the `backstoreOnly` and `cssOnly` options of the `setDimensions` method do all the job for us.

I simplified your code a lot and it seems to work exactly as your one. With "exactly" I mean that both the codes are affected by the same problem.

The problem seems not to be due to your (or my) code, seems to be due to fabric itself; it seems the problem manifests itself when the canvas is higher than the viewport.

If we expand the snippets, we can see both of them work fine until the height of the canvas is lesser than the one of the viewport.

To see the problem in action:

1. expand the snippet
2. resize it to make the canvas higher than the viewport
3. drag the text vertically

I searched for a while on the internet, but I found nothing relevant.

```js
// Create a new instance of Canvas
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
canvas.setDimensions({ width: 1000, height: 1000 }, { backstoreOnly: true });
resizeCanvas();

// Create a new Text instance
var text = new fabric.Text('Texte', {
  fill: '#000',
  fontSize: 100,
  top: 50,
  left: 50,
  borderColor: '#000',
  cornerColor: '#000'
});

// Render the Text on Canvas
canvas.add(text);

// function to resize canvas and its objects
function resizeCanvas() {
  const { clientWidth } = $('.canvas-container')[0];
  const { innerHeight } = window; // viewport height
  const side = Math.min(clientWidth, innerHeight, 1000) + "px";

  canvas.setDimensions({ width: side, height: side }, { cssOnly: true });
}

$(window).resize(resizeCanvas);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #666
}

.upper-canvas {
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/521/fabric.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mx-auto">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="width: 100%;" class="canvas-container">
        <canvas id="canvas" class='img-fluid'>
              <p>This is fallback content for users of assistive technologies or of browsers that don't have full support for the Canvas API.</p>
            </canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer.
I tried your solution but the problem is that I need the canvas to have the following dimensions 1000 x 1000. When I add a text it is too low in the canvas and so it becomes inselectable, the same for the images (I use the fabric.centering.guidelines.js plugin to automatically place them in the center). With my initial code, I don't have this problem. The problem being the selection of objects once the resize is done.

Comment: You can see the selection problem when you go to full page :/

Comment: Pay attention @SKJ ; the problem is not in the selection: the problem is in the relationship between the Y coordinate of the mouse and the Y coordinate of the canvas. To have evidence of it, try to drag only vertically the text (when the canvas is higher than the viewport). Obviously this coordinates relationship problem reflects on a selection problem as well

Comment: Maybe I should use a smaller canvas? I can do it, I just need this canvas to be square. 800x800 for example. What do you think?.

Comment: First of all @SKJ I would open a support request to fabric developers/maintainers; it could be this is a known problem and the already have a solution... or it could be this is actually a bug and they will solve it... or anyway it's better to check what they think about. In the mean while, as a fallback workaround I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. Your code is good but the  canvas dont take all width when you run the snippet. I solved the problem by myself by checking the width during the window resizing and set the maximum to 1000px. Canvas cant get more than 1000px size. Maybe ill open a support request even my problem is fixed. Thank you anyway for taking the time to try to help me.

Comment: It was a pleasure, @SKJ

Comment: Sorry, @SKJ ; you said "the canvas don't take all width", that's true (as intended) when the  full width would be greater than the viewport height. Are there some other cases where you experience this problem? To limit the canvas width to 1000 pixels is enough to change `Math.min(clientWidth, innerHeight)` with `Math.min(clientWidth, innerHeight, 1000)` (as in the updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the extra code in the resize function and limit the maximum containerWidth value to 1000 and i change the class name of the canvas wrapper div to avoid confusion with Fabric.js code.

@Daniele Ricci : thank you for showing me that the canvas bugs when resizing exceeds 1000px. About your solution : the canvas does not take the full width (I should have specified it in my comment but I was talking about the responsive rule of boostrap) of 540px when the snippet is executed. It's 200px, you cant get the object control buttons in the smallest window size.

@the Hutt : thank you for showing me that Fabric.js itself creates a div with the canvas-container class, i hadn't paid attention to it. About your solution: The problem is that the text does not adapt to the right size (especially on the height of this one) when the canvas is in full page.

```js
// Create a new instance of Canvas
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
canvas.setDimensions({width: 1000, height: 1000});
resizeCanvas();

// Create a new Text instance
var text = new fabric.Text('Texte', {
    fill: '#000',
    fontSize: 100,
    borderColor: '#000',
    cornerColor: '#000'
});

// Render the Text on Canvas
canvas.add(text);
canvas.centerObject(text);        
canvas.setActiveObject(text);

// function to resize canvas and its objects
function resizeCanvas() {
  const outerCanvasContainer = $('.canvas-wrapper')[0];
  const ratio = canvas.getWidth() / canvas.getHeight();
  const containerWidth   = ($(outerCanvasContainer).width() > 1000 ? 1000 : outerCanvasContainer.clientWidth);
  console.clear(); console.log(containerWidth);
  const containerHeight  = outerCanvasContainer.clientHeight;
  const scale = containerWidth / canvas.getWidth();
  const zoom  = canvas.getZoom() * scale;

  canvas.setDimensions({width: containerWidth, height: containerWidth / ratio});
  canvas.setViewportTransform([zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0]);
}

$(window).resize(resizeCanvas);
```

```css
body { background-color:#000 }
#canvas{border: 1px solid #666}
.upper-canvas {max-width: 1000px;max-height: 1000px;}
.container{margin:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/521/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/master/lib/aligning_guidelines.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container mx-auto">
   <div class="col-12">           
      <div class="row">
        <div style="width: 100%;" class="canvas-wrapper">
            <canvas id="canvas" class='img-fluid'>
              <p>This is fallback content for users of assistive technologies or of browsers that don't have full support for the Canvas API.</p>
            </canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: First of all there are no bugs with Fabricjs if the size exceeds 1000px. Set size to 2000px and you'll still be able to rotate and resize text as normal. The only issue was you provided extra wrapper with same class. Second, in my answer I've specified what you need to do if you want a square canvas. The text is distorted because I've kept resize logic for height and width separate.